# Why doesn't this function seem to be returning any values

Tags: python, function, return

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def isprime(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    else:
        print(n, "is a prime number")
        return True
def getv():
    x = input("Between what 2 number do you want to check for primes?\n>>\t")
    y = input("Second number.\n>>\t")
    return x
    return y
getv()  
z = int(x) - 1

for n in range(int(z),int(y)):
    isprime(n)
```

Running this, and after inputting the 2 values gets me a NameError: name 'x' is not defined.
It was orignally without the getv() function, but I included it to do a test check on the input variables so that they're only int objects or str and only including numbers. Without the getv() function, it works smoothly. Why isn't the function returning the values?

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from the `getv()` function? It looks like it's coming from the line `z = int(x) - 1` because `x` is not defined by then.

Comment: It is returning a value, but you are not using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually assign those variables to something when you call `getv`:

```
x, y = getv()
```

Also, you can't do two returns in the function, change it to this:

```
return x, y
```

Answer (score 3):

you are calling `getv()` without assigning the returned value to anything. you probably want to do something like this

```
x = getv()
```

or possibly

```
def getv():
    x = input("Between what 2 number do you want to check for primes?\n>>\t")
    y = input("Second number.\n>>\t")
    return x, y

x, y = getv()
```

Note: if you are going to use those values for math, you should turn them into integers with `int()`